# Unable to use Row ID as Hyperlink ID in Kendo Subgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have this sub-grid.  I'm trying to use the row ID (which appears fine on the actual row) .. but is null when I try to use it in the hyperlink inside a ClientTemplate.  The bound column with CTID works fine... number displays.  But it does NOT display when using the link... it shows up as null.

(e.g. http://[link-info-here]/DispForm.aspx?ID=null)

Any help?

```
    <script id="criticalTopicsTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DashboardViewModel>()
     .Name("grid_#=TopicID#")
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.CTID); // CTID does appear here and on the grid
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.CTTitle).Title("CT Name");
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.CTStatus).Title("Status");
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.CTPercentComplete).Title("Percent");
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.CTEnd).Title("Target");
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.CTCertified).Title("Certified");
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.CTOwner).Title("Owner");
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.CTExecStakeholder).Title("Stakeholder");
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.OpenPRs).Title("Open PRs");
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.CompletedPRs).Title("Completed PRs");
         columns.Bound(cr => cr.OtherPRs).Title("Other PRs");
         columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Details").Click("showDetails")).Title("Critical Topic Details");
         columns
         .Bound(cr => cr.CTID) // CTID works here too
         .Template(@<text></text>)
         .Title("Actions")
         .ClientTemplate("<a href='http://<link-info-here>/DispForm.aspx?ID=#=CTID#' target='_blank' class='k-button link'>View</a>" + // CTID = null
                         "<a href='http://<link-info-here>/EditForm.aspx?ID=#=CTID#' target='_blank' class='k-button link'>Edit</a>");  // CTID = null

     })
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Ajax()
     .Read(read => read.Action("GetCriticalTopics", "Hierarchy", new { title = "#=TopicTitle# " }).Data("filterOptions"))
     .PageSize(20)
     )
     .Pageable()
     .Sortable()
     .ClientDetailTemplateId("partnerTemplate")
     .ToClientTemplate()
)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.  Needed to escape the ID.

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href='http://<link-info-here>/DispForm.aspx?ID=\\#=CTID\\#' target='_blank' class='k-button link'>View</a>");
```